# use google app scripts to embed a sheet range in a document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

As you probably know, you can use the web UI to embed a range of a google sheet into a google doc as a linked table that makes it easy to refresh the table in the doc to see any updates in the sheet.

I would like to create this connection via an App Script but I don't see a way to create a table taking a sheet range (or anything like it) as a parameter or any other kind of intelligent object linking. Am I missing something or is there no way to do this short of writing the app script to update this table myself and creating it in each document I make?

Comment: You can get a sheetrange values by using [getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer)) but if you're thinking about copying a table like you would manually (copy paste) using the API, don't think that exist yet. Also, this [google forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/2peIL37pusM) might help. Also related [blog post](http://hellotumo.com/2012/11/28/how-to-embed-specific-cells-when-embedding-a-google-spreadsheet/).

Comment: Thanks for your comments Ruben.  I didn't end up finding a better solution either. Just did an onOpen trigger that updated the table.